# How can convert elequent query to query builder in laravel?

Tags: laravel, lumen

i have query like this:

```
    $user2 = $this->user->query()
        ->select('uid', 'uuid', 'name', 'status')->where('status', 1)
        ->with([
            'roles' => function ($query) {
                $query->select('name');
            },
            'tokens' => function ($query) use ($token) {
                $query->select('uid', 'token', 'type', 'expires')->where('token', $token);
            }
        ])->whereHas('tokens', function (Builder $query) use ($token) {
            $query->where('token', $token)
                ->where('expires', '>=', time())
                ->where('type', 'access');
        })->first()->toArray();
```

i want to convert to query builder.

Comment: Replace "with" method with "join"
and "whereHas" with "where"

Comment: Add roles mode & tokens model details to your question.